# Error Creating a Crowdsale Contract

Tags: solidity

pragma solidity 0.4.16 contract code - Am receiving the following message:

> Could not compile source code
>
> No visibility specified.  Defaulting to "public".
>
> function transfer (address, receiver, uint, amount);
>
> ^ ----------------^  ,

Comment: That's not an error. It's a warning. If you want to get rid of the warning, read what it says. If you still need help, please explain what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the visibility for your function.

```
  function transfer public (address, receiver, uint, amount);
```

For your Info :-

public - all

private - only this contract

internal - only this contract and contracts deriving from it

external - Cannot be accessed internally, only externally.